# How to get grouped values by passing as a key which gets from minimum value in a list

Tags: java, android

```
private String a1, a2, a3, a4;
private String b1, b2, b3, b4;
private int c1, c2, c3, c4;
```

Hello friends, In the above code , I wants to group (a1, b1, c1) , (a2, b2, c2) etc... for remaining value also. (how to group ? 1st question)

And then I created a list thats hold the values {c1, c2, c3, c4}

```
Integer[] arr1 = {c1, c2, c3, c4};
private ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr1));
```

And then I want to get minimum value of list1 and I want to get other two values and store it in another list2 (Ex.if minimum value is c3 , i want to get a3 and b3 and make it combines like this a3 + b3 and i want to store that in list2 . And then I want to remove that c3 value from the list , and again i want to get minimum value from list1 and the above said same operation need to be performed untill the list1 becomes empty.

I tried with using Dictionery , but c1, c2, c3, c4  it have repeated values. so both values also i could'nt take . So need a best solution for my problem. U can also give me any alterate solutions also friends.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is there any chance that alla of the values a1,b1,c1 will be the same with a2,b2,c2;

Comment: No bro . It will be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, this is an easy to understand solution, and has O(n^2) time complexity. If you are to deal with lots and lots of lists i can provide another solution using TreeSet and Comparator. Also two more points:

1. You have to add the c's and the list1,list2, etc in orded as to which the correspond to each other. E.g. if the c1 is to be associated with list1 when you add c1 to myValues list you must add list1 to myLists.
2. You must have the same amount of c's and lists they associate to. E.g. if you have c1,c2,c3 you my have list1,list2,list3 or else an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` will be generated. With that said here is your code.

   ```
   //create a list that will hold all the lists of the a,b
   LinkedList<Integer> myValues = new LinkedList<>();

   int c1 = 1, c2 = 6, c3 = 2;

   myValues.add(c1);
   myValues.add(c2);
   myValues.add(c3);

   LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> myLists = new LinkedList<>();

   LinkedList<String> list1 = new LinkedList<>();
   LinkedList<String> list2 = new LinkedList<>();
   LinkedList<String> list3 = new LinkedList<>();

   myLists.add(list1);
   myLists.add(list2);
   myLists.add(list3);


   String a1 = "a1",b1 = "b1",a2 = "a2",b2 = "b2",a3 = "a3",b3 = "b3";

   list1.add(a1);
   list1.add(b1);
   list2.add(a2);
   list2.add(b2);
   list3.add(a3);
   list3.add(b3);

   myLists.forEach((b) -> b.forEach((s) -> System.out.println(s)));

   //sort the list
   int arrLength = myValues.size();
   for (int i = 0; i < arrLength - 1; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < arrLength - i - 1; j++)
       if (myValues.get(j) > myValues.get(j + 1)) {

       //when you sort the c's you sorth the lists as well
       // swap
       int temp = myValues.get(j);
       myValues.set(j, myValues.get(j + 1));
       myValues.set(j + 1, temp);

       LinkedList<String> tempList = myLists.get(j);
       myLists.set(j, myLists.get(j + 1));
       myLists.set(j + 1, tempList);
       }
   }

   System.out.println("after sorting");
   myLists.forEach((b) -> b.forEach((s) -> System.out.println(s)));


   while(!myValues.isEmpty()) {
       int myC = myValues.pop();
       LinkedList<String> myList = myLists.pop();

       //do your thing
   }
   ```

You can add the above code in a blank main method ,run it,and see how it works.

Comment: 1st of all thanks bro ... And ,    myLists.forEach((b) -> b.forEach((s) -> System.out.println(s)));    what this code 's function ..can u tell me..

Comment: Bro in my problem i will have 10 no.of variables . So what i do to alter that program

Comment: Tqs for all bro .. i found logics for my further issues.... And reframed the program ... And can i have your linked In id ..for my further helps ...and i too helps u further

Comment: This line of code `myLists.forEach((b) -> b.forEach((s) -> System.out.println(s)));` is just for printing the lists in order so you can see it is actually working. Glad you could refactor this to your own needs. If you want anything more feel free to ask. I dont have a linkedin account sorry...

Comment: Ok thanks bro.. any other platforms to communicate with u?? Like Instagram ..fb ?